# how can use multiple function in one instance class php

Tags: php, laravel, oop

need return data like this:

```
Person::firstname('ali')->lastname('hamrani')->age('19');
```

my code :

```
class Person {
    protected $firstname;
    protected $lastname;
    protected $age;

    public static function firstname($firstname)
    {
        $this->$firstname = $firstname;
    }
    public static function lastname($lastname)
    {
        $this->lastname = $lastname;
    }

    public static function age($age)
    {
        $this->age = $age;
    }

    public static function toArray()
    {
        return [
            'firstname' => $this->firstname,
            'lastname' => $this->lastname,
            'age' => $this->age
        ];
    }
}

print_r(Person::firstname('ali')->lastname('hamrani')->age(19)->toArray());
```

i need return for me like this:

```
[
  'firstName' => 'ali',
   'lastName' => 'hamrani',
   'age' => 19,
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps you :

```
class Person {
    protected $firstname;
    protected $lastname;
    protected $age;

    public function firstname($firstname)
    {
        $this->firstname = $firstname;
        return $this;
    }
    public function lastname($lastname)
    {
        $this->lastname = $lastname;
        return $this;
    }

    public function age($age)
    {
        $this->age = $age;
        return $this;
    }

    public function toArray()
    {
        return [
            'firstname' => $this->firstname,
            'lastname' => $this->lastname,
            'age' => $this->age
        ];
    }
}
$person = new Person();
print_r($person->firstname('ali')->lastname('hamrani')->age(19)->toArray());
```

Answer (score 2):

First, if you want to interact with a instance of `Person` and its own attribute, you need to remove all the `static` declarations.

Then, to be able to chain the calls, you can return `$this` (the current object on which you modify a attribute), so the next function can be called on the correct object.

```
class Person {
    protected $firstname;
    protected $lastname;
    protected $age;

    public function firstname($firstname)
    {
        $this->firstname = $firstname;
        return $this ;
    }
    public function lastname($lastname)
    {
        $this->lastname = $lastname;
        return $this ;
    }

    public function age($age)
    {
        $this->age = $age;
        return $this ;
    }

    public function toArray()
    {
        return [
            'firstname' => $this->firstname,
            'lastname' => $this->lastname,
            'age' => $this->age
        ];
    }
}

print_r( (new Person())->firstname('ali')->lastname('hamrani')->age(19)->toArray() );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try passing in the data like so

```
class Person {
    protected $firstname;
    protected $lastname;
    protected $age;

    public static function (Firstname $firstname). * <-like so. 
    {
        $this->$firstname = $firstname;
    }
    public static function (Lastname $lastname)
    {
        $this->lastname = $lastname;
    }
```

And so forth...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can't use the keyword "$this" in a static function. You could instantiate a new "Person" and call each function like so:

```
$someone = new Person();
$someone->firstname('ali');
$someone->lastname('hamrani');
$someone->age('19');
```

then, you can call your function toArray()